# Additinal share options on sharer url

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I am using sharer link on [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qx3tc/) But it isn't possible sending this message to a friend's timeline or sending with a private message with url in demo. I want sending options to be on sharer window like image below. What should i change on sharer url below?
[image]

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?%20app_id=186479208146565&%20link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cruisear.com%2Findex.php%3Fview%3Ds%26artist%3Djohn+lee+hooker%26track%3Di%27m+in+the+mood&%20picture=http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/8623397.jpg&%20name=john+lee+hooker+-+i%27m+in+the+mood&caption=cruisear.com&description=Discover%20new%20artists,%20listen%20new%20songs.&redirect_uri=http://www.cruisear.com" facebook"="" on="" title"share="" target="_blank"><img alt="share on facebook" src="http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo2/img/face.gif">
</a>
```

Comment: You can only post to one other user's wall by also setting the `to` parameter for the dialog beforehand.

Comment: What i have to do to set share option on red box?

Comment: If you want to use that dialog to share to another wall then the user's, set the `to` parameter before. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Even if i put `to` parameter there is only appears person whose id is settled in `to` parameter. Not the pull down menu in picture.

Comment: The feed dialog __does not offer__ that option as of now.

Comment: It is not an obligation as you said it is an offer. So, i stil wonder how to put this pull down menu.